# Can't use QString in a QLineEdit nor QComboBox as a parameter

Tags: c++, qt, qstring, qcombobox, qlineedit

I'm trying to make a function that replace the text inside a QLineEdit when the user want to revert is name to default using a QPushButton.

This is where the code is getting "saved".

```
`//Must get information in the DB
lineditPlayerName = new QLineEdit("Nouveau Profil");
nameAsDefault = new QString(lineditPlayerName->text());
languageAsDefault = new QString(comboBoxlanguage->currentText());`
```

This is the function i use to change the value back to default

```
//This code works
void ProfileManager::revertName(){
    lineditPlayerName->setText("nameAsDefault");
    btnRevertName->setEnabled(false);
}
```

But I need it like this :

```
//This code does'nt
void ProfileManager::revertName(){
    lineditPlayerName->setText(NameAsDefault);
    btnRevertName->setEnabled(false);
}
```

I can't get it to work it give's me this error:
no matching function for call to 'QLineEdit::setText(QString*&)'

Thanks

Comment: Do you really need to dynamically allocate your QString? In Qt I almost never need to do that.

Comment: I've read a tutorial online and that's about all the formation i have... If you can explain why i don't need to do that, it'll be appreciated and can you explain how to do it.

Comment: You want a `QString nameAsDefault` member of your class, not a `QString * nameAsDefault` (pointer to string). You then set it by simply writing `nameAsDefault = lineeditPlayerName->text()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must dereference the `NameAsDefault` variable

```
void ProfileManager::revertName(){
    lineditPlayerName->setText(*NameAsDefault); 
                            // ^ Here I dereferenced the pointer
    btnRevertName->setEnabled(false);
}
```

The type of `nameAsDefault` is **pointer** to a `QString`. However `QLineEdit::setText` expects a `QString` object, not a pointer. Therefore the compiler tells you that there is no function which expects a pointer.

I did not see your declaration of the `nameAsDefault` variable, but since

```
nameAsDefault = new QString(lineditPlayerName->text());
```

compiles and `new` returns a pointer, I suppose it is a pointer.

Also, what is probably more important is that you should almost never allocate objects using `new`. Especially not objects from the `Qt` library, which are implicitly shared.

Comment: Can you explain why, I just need to understand. BTW thanks for the answer.